# Extracting only object type columns in a separate list from a data-frame in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I am a beginner in Python. I want to extract all the column names with DType as object into a separate list for encoding as a part of data processing. What i have tried is the below code, but getting an error

```
l=[]
for i in dataset.columns[i.dtype == 'object']:
    l.append(i)
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 for i in dataset.columns[dataset.dtype == 'object']:
2     print(i)

D:\Anaconda\InstallationFolder\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **getattr**(self, name)
5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
5140
5141     def **setattr**(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
The dataset.info() give the below :

```
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   Loan_ID            614 non-null    object 
 1   Gender             601 non-null    object 
 2   Married            611 non-null    object 
 3   Dependents         599 non-null    object 
 4   Education          614 non-null    object 
 5   Self_Employed      582 non-null    object
```

Please help me with this error.
I want the column names with object data type in a separate list.

Answer (score 3):

You could use it to extract object type and then store it in a variable

```
df.select_dtypes(include='object'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or try selecting the columns using `.select_dtypes()`:

```
col_list = df_flights.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.to_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
columns = [column for column in dataset.columns if dataset[column].dtype == 'object']
```

Comment: It is giving me a blank list

Comment: I tested it and it works. My answer above also works. Please share your code.

Comment: i have used dataset.info() and getting a list of columns along with their datatypes.
as  #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   Loan_ID            614 non-null    object 
 1   Gender             601 non-null    object 
 2   Married            611 non-null    object 
 3   Dependents         599 non-null    object 
 4   Education          614 non-null    object 
 5   Self_Employed      582 non-null    object

Comment: What does dataset.dtypes return?

Answer (score 0):

When using pandas, if you are using a for loop you are probably doing something wrong.

```
dataset.dtypes[dataset.dtypes == "object"].index.values
```

Comment: I tried its not working , what i want is only the column names that are of object datatype in a separate list.

Comment: This should work. I tested it on my own dataframe. What error do you get? This returns an array of column names that are of "object" type.

Comment: I am getting : array([], dtype=object). What the requirement is a list of columns for example  housingtype, gender are two categorical columns. i want a list as 
['housingtype','gender']

Comment: Do you actually have any columns that are object type? What does df.dtypes return?

Comment: Loan_ID               object
Gender                object
Married               object
Dependents            object
Education             object

Comment: it has as i mentioned above  what is the way to share the dataset ?

Comment: Can you show the dataset you are working with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234265/discussion-between-python-learner-and-nick-g).

Answer (score 0):

You are extracting columns so this will work:

```py
l=[]
for i in dataset.columns:
    if dataset[i].dtypes == 'object':
        l.append(i)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if dataset[i].dtype == 'object'`, rather than `dataset[i].dtypes`?